# How is this a subspace?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

So I was given a polynomial vector space  $P_n$(**R**). And a subset $S$ was defined as the set of all polynomials with constant term zero. We had to check whether this set $S$ is a subspace or not .

My teacher told me that it will be a subspace as it satisfies all the properties but then one of my batchmate  asked that this set S will not contain the element "0" as the degree of zero polynomial is not defined. For me that was a legitimate question but the teacher didn't give a satisfactory answer.

**So can someone explain how that set $S$ is a subspace ?**

Comment: The zero polynomial is a polynomial with constant term equal to zero so you may proceed.

Comment: So in your definition the zero polynomial is not even in $P_n(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @JohnDouma but what about its degree ? Shouldn't it satisfy this condition first ?

Comment: @ArcticChar hmm with that definition.. it shouldn't

Comment: Well, so $P_n (\mathbb R)$ is not even a vector space to start with? Can you state precisely what is the definition of $P_n (\mathbb R)$?

Comment: $P_n$ as a vector space must contain the zero polynomial. You should refer to your textbook for the precise definition.

Comment: The concept of degree plays no role in the definition of $S$, does it?

Comment: @ArcticChar isn't it a set of polynomials with degree at most n ?

Comment: Then the zero polynomial is not in $P_n (\mathbb R)$ if you take this as an definition. Is it really how you define it? What I want to point out is that the same problem is there when you first say that $P_n (\mathbb R)$ is a vector space. It has nothing to do with $S$

Comment: It is customary to define the degree of the zero polynomial as $-\infty$ to avoid confusions like this.